# Can't include a file named "config.php" in my PHP app (it gets ignored)

Tags: php, apache, xampp, filenames, require-once

I have the following dir structure:

```
/app
    /controlers
    /models
    /views
    init.php
    config.php
/www
    index.php
```

**/www/index.php** code to call the init file:

```
include_once '../app/init.php';
```

Then in **/app/init.php** I have:

```
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'routes.php';
```

For some reason the **config.php** file is not loading. If I rename it to config2.php and change the include, it is all good. When I switch back to the original name though, it's ignored again. Is there any chance the file name is reserved somehow?

I'm using Apache coming with XAMPP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to include a file from the same directory use

```
require_once './config.php';
require_once './routes.php';
```

or

```
require_once __DIR__.'/config.php';
require_once __DIR__./'routes.php';
```

otherwise a file with same name from your `include_path` may get included instead...